# What's causing this exception?

Tags: c#, exception, webclient, system.net.webexception

What's wrong with this? I get the exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
```

Additional information: An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Here's the part of the code with the WebClient.

I need to learn how to use the code part properly one day....

http://pastebin.com/1Z90bvqB

Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `WebException` causes `WebException`. But without see your work, it is imposible to answer your question.

Comment: Post the (relevant) code here.

Comment: I couldn't get the code format to work correctly, so I included a  link to the code.

Comment: If you are (want ot be) a programmer, learning how to format code here should not take more than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure I agree with the ethics of the code itself, but ignoring that...) a `WebException` is caused by a line that connects to the internet, so either one of the lines like:

```
webClient.DownloadFile(String.Copy(WeepCraft), @"%appdata%\.minecraft\versions");
```

Or the line:

```
Process.Start("http://www.wirez.cf/");
```

In the latter case, unless I'm misunderstanding, is this actually a process you can start??

Anyway, around all the lines, you'll need to have a try/catch for `WebException` in case it can't connect for whatever reason (eg Internet down, wrong URL used, server returns HTTP Error code etc etc), and decide how to handle it.

It's a pretty common Exception whenever something tries to do a http request and the server can't be connected to for whatever reason.